# Having some problem in my responsive image gallery

Tags: html, css

I have made a site [www.carwahi.com](http://www.carwahi.com) using my own HTML & CSS coding but somehow I can't be able to fix the image gallery on my page when viewing in mobile. In mobile view, the images appears to be half the original picture covering half the page.

I am providing my code below although I can't be able to ft in the whole coding in this query area.

I have put the image sizes in pixels in my html code. If you want to check just visit my site & resize the browser to see the problem.

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
.column.middlehome img{max-width: 100%;}
.column.middlehome{max-width: 100%; padding-right: 0; margin-right: 0;}
.column.sidehome{width: 0%;}
.gallery2 img{max-width: 100%; padding-right: 0; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 8%; margin-left: 0;}
.gallery2{max-width: 100%; margin-right: 0%;}
.containerhero{max-width: 100%;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: the plugin you are using for gallery is not responsive, try using this: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
this might solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the changes using developer tool and i got the below output.[image]
Kindly do some correction in your code :

1. add a class for image tag under "Photo Gallery", Here i added `class="banner"`.
2. add style for banner in media query `@media (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 700px){.banner{width: 100%;height: auto;}`
3. change the style for `column.middlehome` and `column.sidehome` in `@media (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 700px)`

`.column.middlehome { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-right: 0; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-left: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}`

And for the `column.sidehome` change the `width:100%`

`@media (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 301px)
.row1 img` remove the left padding There is some space in left side of the (car and bike part) images.

Comment: move media query styles to last/end of the file. If you places media queries at first or middle it will be overwritten.

Comment: In "Cars" section, what did you input in the .column.middlehome area so that it stacked like a column? As there are 2 rows, .column.middlehome & .column.sidehome (Bike section).

Comment: A many thank you @Balaji731, If you can please help me in adjusting the .containerhero1 in home page. Why is the .containerhero1 going out of the .row1 in home page?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `breakpoints` in swiper js to view in mobile like below:
**Breakpoints**: Allows to set different parameter for different responsive breakpoints (screen sizes).

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 2500,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        breakpoints: {
            // when window width is <= 320px
            320: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 10
            },
            // when window width is <= 480px
            480: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 20
            },
            // when window width is <= 640px
            640: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
              spaceBetween: 30
            }
        }

 });
```

Working Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwq0arud/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my main concern is with the "Latest News" section in HOME page, the images appear to be half of the original when mobile viewing. Don't know exactly what is interfering with the images. Please do check.

Answer (score 1):

Give your image in homecontent this CSS.
Also Your column does not have width 50% and contains some padding. Seems like your sidehome and menu at the top is also not being displayed on mobile view too. This must do the work for you. :)

```
@media (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 0px){
 .homecontent img {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   object-fit: cover;
 }
.column.middlehome {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
.column.sidehome {
  width: 46%;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about this [Photo Gallery Page](http://www.carwahi.com/gallery). The problem is occuring for the fixed `height` and `width` you gave.

```
<img src="http://www.carwahi.com/Cars Images/Nissan-Kicks-4.jpg" width="1100" height="700">
```

replace the code to following:

```
<img src="http://www.carwahi.com/Cars Images/Nissan-Kicks-4.jpg" width="85%" height="auto">
```

Here instead of 85% you can give your preferred width. Hope it helps.

```
/* --- New Added Styles --- */
@media (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 301px) {
    .column.sidehome {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .column.middlehome {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .flipcontainer1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 415px;
    }
    .row1 img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    div.gallery2 {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        /* float: left; */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help with the gallery section but my main concern is with my home page, the images in the homepage tends to appear half of its original, don't know what is interfering with that?

Comment: @AbhishekDe Didn't Minal Chauhan's answer solve your problem??? I can see his/her answer is accepted. :/ Do you need more help?

Comment: Minal solved the problem of the slider, but my main concern is with the "Latest News" section in HOME page, the images appear to be half of the original when mobile viewing.

Comment: @AbhishekDe I have updated my answer. Although it doesn't fix all the problems. but some are fixed. You will get some idea from this. Try these and work some more, do some research. And I think you will be able to make your web-page better.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I want an another help from your side, when in mobile view the image just below "Latest News", the content of that image is appearing in an odd section. If you can please help.

Comment: @AbhishekDe Couldn't understand :/ an image would be helpful for me to understand. But I think you should try on your own. that would be best for you to learn by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

slider is not responsive on larger screens as well

see if this works

```
.homeback{
    width : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Partho63, the error is occurring in the "Harley" image & its content just like you can see it in my image. The "Harley" area comes under .column.sidehome & the description comes under .containerhero1.

[image: ***Error occurring in lining up the "Harley" Image & its description.***]